# Cannot get my network running

Tags: networking, routing, nftables

I'm trying to set-up a very small wired/wireless network. One default parameter is : the device on the wired port (eth0) has a static IP address I have to work with. I used a Raspberry PI as Access Point and DHCP server.

[image: This is what's needed]

I need to route the wlan1 to eth0 vice versa.

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

In the RPI with ssh I can ping 192.168.144.12 but if I ping 192.168.144.116 I get reply "From 192.168.144.12 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable"

return from:
ip neigh

- 192.168.2.254 dev wlan0 lladdr 50:78:b3:a1:e4:d1 STALE
- 192.168.144.118 dev wlan1  FAILED
- 192.168.144.103 dev eth0  FAILED
- 192.168.144.103 dev wlan1 lladdr bc:83:85:06:5c:32 STALE
- 192.168.144.12 dev eth0 lladdr 60:78:f5:e8:81:0f STALE
- 192.168.144.12 dev wlan1  FAILED
- 192.168.2.252 dev wlan0 lladdr f8:08:4f:88:13:53 STALE
- 192.168.2.22 dev wlan0 lladdr ac:b5:7d:6c:24:37 REACHABLE
- fe80::5278:b3ff:fea1:e4d1 dev wlan0 lladdr 50:78:b3:a1:e4:d1 router REACHABLE
- fe80::6278:f5ff:fee8:810f dev eth0 lladdr 60:78:f5:e8:81:0f router REACHABLE

The return from: nft list ruleset

```
table ip ap {
        chain apincomming {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                ct state established,related accept
        }

        chain aprouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
                oifname "eth0" masquerade
        }
}
```

Does someone can give me a pointer, I would be grateful

---

```
The response from ip route:
default via 192.168.144.12 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.144.118 metric 202
default via 192.168.2.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.18 metric 303
default via 192.168.144.1 dev wlan1 src 192.168.144.100 metric 304
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.18 metric 303
192.168.144.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.144.118 metric 202
192.168.144.0/24 dev wlan1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.144.100 metric 304
```

Comment: Just to be sure, did you rebooted the machine? `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is just a file which it is read only at boot (or with sysctl command). Note: you need to show also the routing table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I rebooted lots of times. Been trying to solve this issues for days

Comment: The configuration of host RPI in your diagram is a bridge.  Have you enabled bridging on RPI? See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363332/how-do-i-configure-a-network-interface-bridge-from-wifi-to-ethernet-with-debian).

Comment: Thank you very much. Bridge is the solution!

Comment: Your RPI is an Access Point so it can use a wireless interface as bridge port. I assume you do want to use a bridge because it's the same IP LAN left and right. But your schematic shows 1 IP address per physical interface, while these interface which are now bridge port must not have any: the address has to be on the bridge interface but I can see none. Can you update your schematic to make the bridge appear, then give the configuration of all 3 interfaces?